# Convert YYYYDDD String to YYYYMMDD in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to convert a date format of YYYYDDD such as 2007001 to its  YYYYMMDD equivalent (2007-01-01) in BigQuery within the SQL statement?

Comment: How would October 15 look in this notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date_in_yyyyddd,
  DATE_ADD(
    DATE(CAST(SUBSTR(date_in_yyyyddd, 1, 4) AS INT64),1,1), 
    INTERVAL CAST(SUBSTR(date_in_yyyyddd, 5, 3) AS INT64) - 1 DAY
  ) date_in_yyyymmdd
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '2007001' date_in_yyyyddd UNION ALL
  SELECT '2007031' date_in_yyyyddd UNION ALL
  SELECT '2007061' date_in_yyyyddd 
)
SELECT date_in_yyyyddd,
  DATE_ADD(
    DATE(CAST(SUBSTR(date_in_yyyyddd, 1, 4) AS INT64),1,1), 
    INTERVAL CAST(SUBSTR(date_in_yyyyddd, 5, 3) AS INT64) - 1 DAY
  ) date_in_yyyymmdd
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row date_in_yyyyddd date_in_yyyymmdd     
1   2007001         2007-01-01   
2   2007031         2007-01-31   
3   2007061         2007-03-02
```

Above produces date type of field with format of yyyy-mm-dd
In case if you need format of yyyymmdd you can add FORMAT_DATE as in below example

```
SELECT date_in_yyyyddd,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(
    DATE(CAST(SUBSTR(date_in_yyyyddd, 1, 4) AS INT64),1,1), 
    INTERVAL CAST(SUBSTR(date_in_yyyyddd, 5, 3) AS INT64) - 1 DAY
  )) date_in_yyyymmdd
```

so same result will now look as

```
Row date_in_yyyyddd date_in_yyyymmdd     
1   2007001         20070101     
2   2007031         20070131     
3   2007061         20070302
```